# why my basic terraform fails to run terraform plan?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have this very basic terraform file: `main.tf`

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.16"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.2.0"
}

provider "aws" {
    profile = "default"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "test-bucket-terraform-regergjegreg" {
  bucket = "test-bucket-terraform-regergjegreg"

  tags = {
    Name        = "My bucket"
    Environment = "Dev"
  }
}
```

when doing `terraform validate`, I have no error:
`Success! The configuration is valid.`

Now when I do `terraform plan`, I got this error:

```
Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.

╷
│ Error: configuring Terraform AWS Provider: credential type source_profile requires role_arn, profile default
│ 
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
│   on main.tf line 12, in provider "aws":
│   12: provider "aws" {
│ 
╵
```

Here is my terraform version:

```
Terraform v1.4.6
on darwin_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.76.1
```

the default profile exists in my /.aws/credentials and /.aws/config

Not sure what could be wrong really. Any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: What version of terraform are you using?

Comment: I have updated the question:
Terraform v1.4.6
on darwin_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.76.1

Comment: That's an ancient version of the `aws` provider. The latest is 5.0.1. I guess, it's time to upgrade.

Comment: Upgrading did the trick in this [issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/9999).

Comment: still not working. I deleted everything and use 5.0.1, still no luck

Comment: As a guess, your "default" profile in `$HOME/aws/config` has a problem. What happens if you run `aws sts get-caller-identity --profile default`?

Comment: it works, it returns me the UserId, Account and Arn
I'm using macos by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I resolved the issue.
My problem was not in credentials file but in config.
For some reason I had this:

```
[default]
output = json
region = eu-west-1
source_profile = default
```

removing source_profile makes it work.